# I was trying to directly send in values to my array as parameter but it does not work

Tags: java, arrays, call-by-value

It works if I initialize those values in another array and then pass it in the main function. Is it something that I am doing wrong or is it just we cannot directly pass values? Here are both the codes:-
Using Array to Pass:-

```
public class DDArray {
    void array(int[][] a){
        int x=a.length;
        int y=a[0].length;
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<y;j++){
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        DDArray ob=new DDArray();
        int[][] b={{1,2,3,4,5},{11,22,33,44,55}};
        ob.array(b);
    }
}
```

Directly Passing:-

```
public class DDArray {
    void array(int[][] a){
        int x=a.length;
        int y=a[0].length;
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<y;j++){
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        DDArray ob=new DDArray();
        ob.array({{1,2,3,4,5},{11,22,33,44,55}});
    }
}
```

Comment: u cannot use array initializer as method parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change in direct call from 
ob.array({{1,2,3,4,5},{11,22,33,44,55}}); 
to 
ob.array(**new int[][]** { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, { 11, 22, 33, 44, 55 } });

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Solution. Even my teacher couldn’t figure this out. He is going to be so shocked

Comment: Great, Happy to help. Please upvote the answer too ;)

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question, you can't directly pass values like that. Compiler will complain for the same. Compiler error is pretty straightforward here - *Array initializer is not allowed here.*